# How to adjust text formatting in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Given the image above, the description column contains data that cannot be altered. I would like to create a separate column that changes the formatting to exactly what is shown in columns AD,AE, and AF that also include spaces for every data in the description column. My attempt at doing so is in column AB where the formula used is

```
=[@Sym] & "" & TEXT(X12,"mmmm'yy") & "" &  Z2  & "" & IF(AB1= "A", "B")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows Office 365, you can use:

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
     y, TEXT(INDEX(x,2),"mmmdd\'yy"), 
     TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(x,1),y,INDEX(x,{3,4})))
```

*Change A1 to proper cell reference*

[image]

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can use this longer formula:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99)),1)
&TEXT(--INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99)),2)," mmmdd\'yy")
& " " & --INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99)),3)
& " " & INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*99),99)),4)
```

where **seq** is a **Name** referring to: `=ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))`